# Converting velocity response to JSON

Tags: json, struts2, velocity

I am using struts 2 and velocity templates to generate JSON response.
Now the catch is the response is not generated using some velocity JSON plugin
it's just a String that comes out once velocity is done with its parsing and rendering of
response, and on client side I do *eval* to get the response from string to JSON.

What I really need is some solution on velocity's or struts' side where, once the result is
generated by velocity, the framework should call my API where I can convert the response output of vm file into JSON using my own logic. How do achieve this?

For example:

1. On browser using JavaScript I have designed a tree widget that I use for displaying comments in tree structure.
2. Say user clicks on comments button.
3. My UI widget will fire an AJAX to get data for comments.
4. This request is intercepted by STRUTS 2 framework.
5. It will call, say, `getComments()` action API and will populate an arrayList with comment object say cmt.
6. Now the response is handled by a velocity template(*.vm).
7. Now in vm I am writing code like this:

   ```
   { "CommentsData" : [

       #set($sep="")
       #foreach($c in $cmt)
       $sep
       {
           "commentText" : $c.getText()
       }
       #set($sep=",")
       #end

   }
   ```
8. Now the final response may turn out like this:

   ```
   { "CommentsData" : [

       {
           "commentText" : "This is comment 1"
       },
       {
           "commentText" : "This is comment 2"
       },
       {
           "commentText" : "This is comment 3"
       },
       {
           "commentText" : "This is comment 4"
       }`

       ]
   }
   ```
9. Now this may look like JSON, but its not strict JSON; I mean if I miss
   some `,` somewhere then on client side in JavaScript my *eval* might fail or `JSON.parse()`
   will fail, but on velocity template I have now clue if JSON is malformed.
10. So once the above velocity template is generated I need some control, where I can write some Java code to do some validations on the response.

I see that my approach to use velocity template to generate JSON output (actully a String that looks like JSON) may be wrong. But still I need to handle the response of every velocity template I have written.

Comment: If you're outputting JSON, there's no need for templating(velocity).  Maybe you use velocity differently from me, but I fail to see how a template would be useful in outputting json. An example of what you're doing will clarify things

Comment: quite confusing to me.what you doing with VM.as that is something tempelating Engine.a full user case help to get you some inputs

Comment: This is a bad use for templating, it's confusing ane error prone code. You don't need it to create JSON. Just use a JSON library to generate the output

Comment: Why don't you over-complicating the process when even struts2 have json plugin which take care of converting your list to well formatted JSON data

Comment: If you want to validate your JSON, try parsing it with anything that parses JSON. You should do that in your tests, not in the live system. As others mention, while you *can* generate JSON this way, it seems a little pointless given the numerous alternatives--none of which would require a validation step.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you are using velocity. We don't use velocity when outputting JSON; we just create a JSON convertible object and output it directly from controllers using `response.write(jsonObject.toJson())`. This way, proper JSON is always generated.